# Html vertically align elements that were in a row.

Tags: html, css

I have 4 elements in each row within the table. At a certain page width with css i want each row to only contain 1 label and 1 text box with the other elements jumping below. [![enter image description here][1]][1]`

```
        <! Legend to group player information>
        <legend class="legend_player_information" align="center">Player Information</legend>

        <! Table labeling the table within player information>
        <table class="table_player_information" align="center">

            <! Row 1 within player information>
            <tr class="row_player_information_name">
                <td class="element_player_information_name_label" valign="top"><label for="element_player_information_name_label">Name:</label></td>

                <td class="element_player_information_name_text" valign="top"><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="element_player_information_name_text" maxlength="50" size="20"></td>

                <td class="element_player_information_nickname_label" valign="top"><label for="element_player_information_nickname_label">Nickname:</label></td>

                <td class="element_player_information_nickname_text" valign="top"><input type="text" placeholder="Nickname" name="element_player_information_nickname_text" maxlength="30" size="20"></td>
            </tr>

            <! Row 2 within player information>
            <tr class="row_player_information_email_address">

                <td class="element_player_information_email_address_label" valign="top"><label for="element_player_information_email_address_label">Email Address:</label></td>

                <td class="element_player_information_email_address_text" valign="top"><input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" name="element_player_information_email_address_text" maxlength="50" size="20"></td>

                <td class="element_player_information_school_label" valign="top"><label for="element_player_information_school_label">School:</label></td>

                <td class="element_player_information_school_text" valign="top"><input type="text" placeholder="School" name="element_player_information_school_text" maxlength="30" size="20"></td>
            </tr>
```

`

Comment: Does it have to be a table?

Comment: probably not but i spent a lot of time to get it in a table because i liked the way it looked with the page normal. Now i'm just working on if it were accessed from a phone. I wish i could show you a picture but i don't have the reputation

Comment: something along these lines (re-size screen for effect): http://jsfiddle.net/uw99Lj1j/

Comment: Now how would that work if i want to leave the 4 elements in the row to begin?

Comment: The four elements are in a row by default. The won't leave the row unless other properties are applied. In the demo, they move into a single column when the screen size is < 300px.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for your help! How would i leave it so there are 2 elements in each row though?

Comment: For two elements in a row simply wrap two elements in a container and do the same thing as the first demo.. http://jsfiddle.net/uw99Lj1j/3/

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to display a table row in multiple rows. Better way is to use div blocks and to overwrite their style depending on the screen size. This should do the trick:

```
    @media (max-width:desired width){
    your styles
    }
```

Moreover, you can use bootstrap grid system to do everything by only adding classes to your div blocks http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries.

Comment: table row? if i rewrite it would it be easier for styling?

Comment: As I understood you want a `<td>` to be 100% width at a certain page width, but table data is not intended to be a row. In other words, if you have two `<td>` in one `<tr>` and you set a `<td>` width to 100% you still will get two `<td>` in a row. As I've already said you can use divs instead of table and change their width depending on the screen size. So, it would be not easier, but possible for styling. And using bootstrap will surely make it faster to code and likely more accurate.